# Modifying value of component's parent properties, use toRefs or not, in composition api

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have a nested structure of components whose structure is defined by nested arrays.

When I want to delete a component, I need to access the parent's component child-array variable residing on the parent's props, in order to find the component there and splice it out of the child-array.

```js
{ 
  id:'p0',
  name:'parent',
  children:[
    { id:'p0c1-w4f5',name:'child1', children:[]},
    { id:'p0c2-wsad',name:'child2', children:[]},
  ]
}
```

When `child1` requests its deletion it executes the following code

```js
const remove1 = (id) => {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance();
  const p = instance.parent;
  var p_children = p.props.children // <--- xxxxx without toRefs xxxxx
  var remove_index = null;
  p_children.forEach((e, index) => {
    if (e.id == id) {
      remove_index = index;
    }
  })
  p_children.splice(remove_index, 1)
}
```

or should I use

```js
const remove2 = (id) => {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance();
  const p = instance.parent;
  const { children } = toRefs(p.props) // <--- xxxxx with toRefs xxxxx
  var remove_index = null;
  children.value.forEach((e, index) => {
    if (e.id == id) {
      remove_index = index;
    }
  })
  children.value.splice(remove_index, 1)
}
```

Both approaches work, but I would like to know if just using the first one is OK, and why it is not necessary to use `toRefs` on the parent props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const { children } = toRefs(p.props)`

`toRefs` would be needed if you were planning to pass that `children` variable around or store it somewhere for future use and keep it reactive (so when parent props are changed, `children` variable would too). But since you are not doing anything of that, `toRefs` is not needed at all...

Otherwise I found accessing parent props from child like that very strange. I don't like it. IMHO better is to move that logic into a parent and let the child emit the event the parent handles.

Comment: What would be the best way to notify a parent for deletion if there were other components in between which I don't have access to? This is in the context of `vue.draggable.next`, where the `draggable` component sits between the parent and the child. https://sortablejs.github.io/vue.draggable.next/#/nested-example

Comment: @DanielF I do not have any xp with vue.draggable. But it seems strange you have access to parent with `getCurrentInstance().parent`. Or is the `parent` in this case the draggable component?

Comment: I'm actually using `instance.parent.parent.parent` for this to work, which is ugly and inflexible, and your comment in the answer made me think that what you say is what I should be doing, notifying the parent for it to take care of it. I'll search the documentation and tutorials. Thanks for getting me in the correct direction.

Comment: I see. There are at least two better ways. Either use some central store (Vuex, Pinia ...but creating a simple store in Vue 3 is easy too), move the data from topless parent into a store and let children work with the store only. Or use [provide / inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#provide-inject)